# Maximize window button is missing on all programs

Tags: compiz, window-buttons

The maximize button is gone on all programs, Although it does appear on Chrome and Firefox. I would like all programs to have all 3 options (close, minimize, maximize). How can I fix this issue? It was working at one point, But now I only get minimize and close.

Comment: I Would like to know which version of Ubuntu you are using.
11.10 or 12.04 and Which environment Unity or Gnome??
Coz the solutions differ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay Seeing your tags,I figure out you are using Ubuntu 12.04 and Unity interface,

Do the following-

1. If you do not have UBUNTU TWEAK,install it.
2. Go to TWEAKS tab
3. Select WINDOW from DESKTOP section.
4. Switch OFF the "Close only" option.
   Hope it works.. :)

Comment: You got it right, except it moved everything to the the left.  I had to go into gconf and edit it so the buttons go to the right.  I apologize for the lack of information.

Comment: I appreciate the help, BUT, it should not be so hard to fix these issues. More importantly, it really should not happen at all.  What caused it?  This is what makes Linux not a viable Desktop option for more than a few enthusiasts. Sorry if I appear grumpy.  :)

Comment: I agree with @chazdg.  This is the second time Ubuntu has made a strange decision to change the expected behaviour of their window controls.  First they moved everything to the left and mucked up the order, causing mass hysteria... now they've decided we neither need to minimise or maximise, nor do we need to have a simple menu option to turn them on should we decide we want them.  Why do we need to hack the interface to get things right again?  Was there good justification for this, or like the move to the left was it simply an arrogant change with no right of reply by someone at Canonical?

Comment: `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks && gnome-tweaks`